# Face detection Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create an application that extract the faces from a video (extracting frames when is detecting faces). Do you know any good library that i can use? After extraction i want to compare the frames extracted with other photos.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a library can do that in Xamarin , but Xamarin allows you to use native Android API , so i think you can access any java code for android from Xamarin.Android project . Search for java code or api can do that and try to access it from your Xamarin.Android using c#

Answer (score 0):

EmguCV is .NET implementation of OpenCV and it's available for xamarin.
Here is the link:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/emgucv-v3

I used EmguCV to recognize faces from the video stream and images in WPF application and I guess that this library will also work fine in the Xamarin.Android application.